# How can I implement an iOS app with facebook like Diamond Dash?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I have found long time online but can't found the tutorial. So I ask here. Hope someone can share experience to me.

I have made an simple puzzle game for iOS and I want to:

1. Make a leaderboard for the game score with facebook game.
2. Implement that request to friend for life, like the game Diamond Dash.

I show the picture followed as reference:
[image]

I want my puzzle game has this two function like Diamond Dash.

Can anyone help me where can I find the tutorial for these?

Comment: Why vote this question down and no any explanation?
I just want to know more skills. Isn't this website for this ??? =(

Comment: "Questions asking us to *recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Asking for tutorials is considered off-topic for stackoverflow, see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1):

Did you look the samples at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-games

? they are pretty straightforward.

Comment: I saw this before. However, the example use C++ to implement. I am new to C++ and I guess there is something i need to do for import C++. Do I need to use C++ for the purpose only?
Or Is there any another I can follow?

Comment: Just rename your file to .mm and you're ready to go! mm are Objective C++ files, which means you can mix your objective C code with C++

Comment: just change .m files to be .mm?? any other I need to change?? I have no experience about this

Comment: that is if you want to use Objective C++ in Xcode. Everything else is well explained in the samples, so you should start studying those. Otherwise your question is too generic.